# Flash CS3 being weird. Rightbrace unexpected 1083

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, syntax-error

This simple code keeps annoying the heck outta me. When I put the rightbrace at the end(Error 1083), it says it is unexpected. But, when I take it away, it says it is expecting one, Error 1084:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,floattowards);

function floattowards(e:Event):void{

    hg.x=mouseX;
    hg.y=mouseY;
    hr.x=254+
    hr.y=123-
    hb.x=++
    hb.y=++

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it won't work, you've written your assignment operators in wrong sequence of signs, therefore they are being compiled as a single uninterrupted expression:

```
hr.x=254+hr.y = 123-hb.x = ++hb.y = ++<expression expected>
```

Thus an expression is unfinished. You need to learn where to put plus/minus signs first if you plan to increment or decrement variables. A correct way of incrementing is writing the expression without equal sign:

```
hb.x++;
```

And don't forget the semicolons, lacking one in an expression can make one expression out of two with unexpected results. So, rewrite your function and place semicolons after each assignment. No hanging +/- signs either.